# Click to confirm a Modal Dialog with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, webdriver

I have a Modal Dialog like this:
[image]

And I want to click on OK button to save this text. So I use switchTo to switch to this dialog:

```
webDriver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

I assumed since there is only one Dialog, so I used frameID = 0. But I don't know how to proceed forward from here or how to click on the OK button, because I don't get any HTML info.

Any help much appreicated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like not frame. If it is frame then you can insect those buttons. So are you able to inspect those buttons? if not then it is alert which is cased by javascript. Use switch to alert here

```
   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept(); // for OK
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 5):

Hi thats not frame that's alert and there is Alert method defined in selenium for performing action :Below are the various operations that you can perform on alerts (for more operations look official documentation)

```
        // working with alerts.
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        // for clicking on ok button
        alert.accept();
        // for clicking on cancel button
        alert.dismiss();
        // for getting alert text message
        alert.getText();
        // for sending some text inside the alert
        alert.sendKeys("alert string");
```